# Find two sets of polar coordinates for the point between $0\leq \theta <2\pi$

Tags: polar-coordinates

The point is $\left(-2\sqrt{3},-2\right)$

Using  the formula $x^2 +y^2=r^2$ and $\tan(\frac{y}{x})$, plugging in we get
$$(-2\sqrt{3})^2+(-2)^2=r^2$$
$$r=4$$
$$\tan(\frac{-2}{-2\sqrt{3}})=\tan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$
So my question is, which set of coordinates is correct?
$$\left(4, \frac{\pi}{6}\right),\left(-4,\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$$
or 
$$\left(-4, \frac{\pi}{6}\right),\left(4,\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$$

Comment: Think about which quadrant the point is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the point $\left(-2\sqrt{3},-2\right)$ is in the third quadrant ($x$- and $y$- coordinates are negative),

the correct set of coordinates must be the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x<0$ we have that

$$\theta = \arctan \frac y x + \pi$$

with $r\ge0$ of course, since negative values for $r$ are not allowed, therefore $(r, \theta)=\left(4,\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$.

Refer also to [Converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).